# PHP read file match if statement

Tags: php, file, if-statement, conditional-statements

everyone I have the following file and I want to show lines that match on if condition and pass the other.

I have this TXT file:

```
Doc. number|Date|Price|Description|Name
100|11/11/2015|99|Test 1|Alex
101|11/11/2015|120|Test 2
102|11/11/2015|100|Test 3|John
102|11/11/2015|140||
103|11/11/2015|110|Test 4|
```

And this is my PHP code:

```
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
$i = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Doc. number</th><th>Date</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('|', $line_of_text);

    if($i > 1) { // Pass the first line
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $parts[0] . "</td>"; // Doc. number
            echo "<td>" . $parts[1] . "</td>"; // Date
            echo "<td>" . $parts[2] . "</td>"; // Price
            echo "<td>" . $parts[3] . "</td>"; // Description
            echo "<td>" . $parts[4] . "</td>"; // Name

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $i++;
}

fclose($file_handle);
echo "</table>"
```

How I can check if there are no "Description" and/or "Name" in table and pass this line. I want to show(get) only line that match on if condition.

I will be very grateful if someone have idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know that `$parts[3]` and `$parts[4]` have always `Description` and `Name` respectively. So in every iteration Check them. If they exist in array execute the if-body, neither pass the iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as

```
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
$i = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Doc. number</th><th>Date</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('|', $line_of_text);

    if($i > 1 && !empty($parts[3]) && !empty($parts[4])) { // Pass the first line and lines without description / name
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $parts[0] . "</td>"; // Doc. number
            echo "<td>" . $parts[1] . "</td>"; // Date
            echo "<td>" . $parts[2] . "</td>"; // Price
            echo "<td>" . $parts[3] . "</td>"; // Description
            echo "<td>" . $parts[4] . "</td>"; // Name

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    $i++;
}

fclose($file_handle);
echo "</table>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Only print table row if we have name and description:

```
if($i > 1 && $parts[3] && $parts[4]) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put condition before echo statement and if it will be false just skip "echo";

```
if (count($parts) === 5) {
    $error = 0;
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
       if (empty($part)) error++;
    }

    if($i > 1 && $error === 0) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $parts[0] . "</td>"; // Doc. number
                echo "<td>" . $parts[1] . "</td>"; // Date
                echo "<td>" . $parts[2] . "</td>"; // Price
                echo "<td>" . $parts[3] . "</td>"; // Description
                echo "<td>" . $parts[4] . "</td>"; // Name

            echo "</tr>";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've a solution that can help you.
But why I think you need just scape the heading line. so I changed if($i > 1) to be if($i >0)

```
$file_handle = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
$i = 0;
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr><th>Doc. number</th><th>Date</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th><th>Name</th></tr>";
while (!feof($file_handle)) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('|', $line_of_text);
    if($i > 0) { // Pass the first line
        if ( (!empty($parts[3])) && (!empty($parts[4])) ){
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" . $parts[0] . "</td>"; // Doc. number
                echo "<td>" . $parts[1] . "</td>"; // Date
                echo "<td>" . $parts[2] . "</td>"; // Price
                echo "<td>" . $parts[3] . "</td>"; // Description
                echo "<td>" . $parts[4] . "</td>"; // Name
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    $i++;
}
fclose($file_handle);
echo "</table>"
```

Comment: That will get to you: Alex & John Rows.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has a `CSV` structure, pipe delimited.
So parse it as a `CSV`.

Note the using of [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) to get the header of the CSV and passing the delimiter parameter to [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Also consider using `implode` instead explicitly passing each member of the array between `td` tags.

Here's an example using two functions, one for parsing the `CSV` and returning the data,
and another one for displaying the data and doing the validation.

```
function getData($file){

    $rows = array();

    if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, null, "|")) !== FALSE) {

            $rows[] = $data;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    }

    return $rows;

}

function displayData($rows){

    $header = array_shift($rows);
    $output = '<table border="1">' . PHP_EOL;
    $output .= '<tr><th>' . implode('</th><th>',$header) . '</th></tr>' . PHP_EOL;

    foreach($rows as $row){

        if (isset($row[3]) and isset($row[4]) and $row[3]!='' and $row[4]!=''){
            $output .= '<tr><td>' . implode('</td><td>',$row) . '</td></tr>' . PHP_EOL;
        }

    }

    $output .= '</table>';
    return $output;

}

$rows = getData("pipe.txt");

print displayData($rows);
```

This will output the following

```
<table border="1">
<tr><th>Doc. number</th><th>Date</th><th>Price</th><th>Description</th><th>Name</th></tr>
<tr><td>100</td><td>11/11/2015</td><td>99</td><td>Test 1</td><td>Alex</td></tr>
<tr><td>102</td><td>11/11/2015</td><td>100</td><td>Test 3</td><td>John</td></tr>
</table>
```